# How to echo 2011-01-31 as 31 January 2011?

Tags: php, date, date-format

How I can echo 2011-01-31 as 31 January 2011?
The input (2011-01-31) comes from the database (type: date).

Also is there any option to use locale names for the month?

Edit:

```
$date = date_create($row['bdate']);
echo date_format($date, 'd F Y'); //31 January 2010
```

could be solution but `date_format` has no option for other languages(?). Is there any solution? Like 31 Ocak 2011

Comment: I wonder why anyone would want to depart from the beauty of ISO 8601 :(

Comment: @Joey, because when I see 01-02-2011 on any web site I think: "WTF is this now? Which one is month and which one is day?! Arr! Just click the damn close tab button and never visit that stupid site again..." On the other hand 2 Ocak 2011 or 1 Şubat 2011 is clear.

Comment: ilhan: It was partly meant in jest. However, YYYY-MM-DD is unambiguous, too. And sorts well :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably is [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) what you seek.

Example:
`echo strftime('%d %B %Y', strtotime($db_entry));`

Answer (score 4):

Use `strtotime` to convert `2011-01-31` to a timestamp:

```
echo date( 'd F Y', strtotime( $row['bdate'] ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

echo date('d F Y', strtotime("2011-01-31"));
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/WPe1xCFz

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`strftime()`](http://php.net/strftime)

```
$date = strtotime($row['bdate']);
echo strftime('%d %B %Y', $date);
```